# c# - Check equality of complex object

Tags: c#

2 objects of same class have same information, only difference the indexes of list have data interchanged.
I was checking Linq Intersect and Except operator, how would i get the expected result from them? I have more complex objects with list containing lists in them.
The below code on debug never steps into operator methods. May be i am making a mistake here.
can anyone guide me.

**Sample Book Class**

```
class Book
{
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Chapter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

class Page
{
    public int number { get; set; }

}
```

**I have created helper class using iEqualityComparer**

```
  class ChapterComparer : IEqualityComparer<Chapter>
{
    public bool Equals(Chapter x, Chapter y)
    {
        if (string.Equals(x.name, y.name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {   
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Chapter obj)
    {
        return obj.name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class BookComprarer : IEqualityComparer<Book>
{
    public bool Equals(Book x, Book y)
    {
        if (string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (x.Chapters.Except(y.Chapters, new ChapterComparer()).Any() != false)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Book obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Here i generate Book data**

```
private Book GetBookUpdate()
    {
        return new Book()
        {
            Name = "Book 1",
           Chapters = new List<Chapter>()
           { 
                new Chapter()
                { 
                    name = "Story 1",
                    Pages = new List<Page>()
                    { 
                        new Page()
                        { 
                            number = 2
                        },
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 3
                        },
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 4
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Chapter()
                {
                    name = "Story 2",
                    Pages = new List<Page>()
                    {
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 5
                        },
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 6
                        },
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 7
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        };
    }

    private Book GetLocalBook()
    {
        return new Book()
        {
            Name = "Book 1",
            Chapters = new List<Chapter>()
           {
                new Chapter()
                {
                    name = "Story 2",
                    Pages = new List<Page>()
                    {
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 5
                        },
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 6
                        },
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 7
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Chapter()
                {
                    name = "Story 1",
                    Pages = new List<Page>()
                    {
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 2
                        },
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 3
                        },
                        new Page()
                        {
                            number = 4
                        }

                    }
                }                    
           }
        };
    }
}
```

Here i created method for comparing it.

```
public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Book r1 = GetLocalBook();
        Book r2 = GetBookUpdate();


        var d = r1.Equals(r2);

    }
```

Comment: Would `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` help?

Comment: It works if the indexes in list has same data, if i swap the data, it is not working.

Comment: Maybe `OrderBy` it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an IEqualityComparer, you cannot just use Equals(). Also, [Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1) that you inherit from [EqualityComprarer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1) instead :

> We recommend that you derive from the EqualityComparer class instead of implementing the IEqualityComparer interface

Then, you must ask yourself what it means for a Book to be equal to another one. If can be either :

1. Both have the same name and the same chapters, even if not in the same order

or

2. Both have the same name and the same chapters in the same order

if you go with option 1, then just sort the items ([using OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__)) in the lists before comparing (using [Linq method SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__)):

```
class BookComprarer : EqualityComparer<Book>
{
    public override bool Equals(Book b1, Book b2)
    {
        if (b1 == null || b2 == null)
            return false;
        if (!string.Equals(b1.Name, b2.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return false;
        ChapterComparer cmp = new ChapterComparer();
        //If you go with option 2, just use bx.Chapters;
        var c1 = b1.Chapters.OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToLower()); //ToLower so we ignore case
        var c2 = b2.Chapters.OrderBy(x => x.Name.ToLower());
        return c1.SequenceEquals(c2, cmp);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Book obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Same goes for Chapter Comparison, if you want or not to include the pages in the comparison or not.

Then, you need to compare two books :

```
BookComparer cmp = new BoolComparer();
Book b1 = GetLocalBook();
Book b2 = GetBookUpdate();

bool areBookEquals = cmp.Equals(b1, b2);
```

Comment: I have a production data where the object have multi level child objects that i need to compare. Now i have a better idea what has to be done. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

When books x and y has got same chapters, x.Chapters.Except(y.Chaters, ...).Any() will be false (x does not have any chapters which are not in y), so condition should be

```
if (x.Chapters.Except(y.Chapters, new ChapterComparer()).Any() == false)
```

Also, you need to use BookComparer when comparing books:

```
var d = new BookComprarer().Equals(r1, r2);
```